# add sum of frst col to sum of all the other cols

Tags: function, sum, duplicates

In Excel, I want to sum rows 2 and 3 from Col. B to the sum of the remaining cols. C thru M.  I can do it manually, but I want to be able to just do 2 or 3 cols. and then Drag over to duplicate the function in the remaining columns, but when I drag, it does not use the constant column, it increments the col B identifier as well.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your file?

Answer (score 0):

In the first box that you input your equation into, add a $ sign before the number terms you want to remain constant.

For example in the box C4 you could enter `=C2+C3-($B$2+$C$3)` then after pulling the equation to the right across your other columns C2 and C3 will change to D2 D3, E2 E3, etc.